# Realizations of symmetric groups as subgroups of larger symmetric groups

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let's say I want to know what all the subgroups of $S_n$ that are isomorphic to $S_m$ look like, where $m < n$.  Do these have a nice characterization?  For example, is it true that every such subgroup acts as $S_m$ when restricted to an appropriate $m$ element subset?

Comment: The answer to the last question is no. Consider the subgroup of $S_6$ isomorphic to $S_3$ that acts as $S_3$ on $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{4,5,6\}$ separately. Now make every element that corresponds to an odd permutation in $S_3$ also swap the two  sets. This subgroup is still isomorphic to $S_3$, but now it acts transitively and you can't restrict it to any $3$-element subset.

Comment: Concretely, this is the subgroup of $S_6$ formed by $(123)(456)$, $(132)(465)$, $(15)(24)(36)$, $(16)(34)(25)$, $(26)(35)(14)$ and the identity.

Comment: Your conjecture is correct when $m > n/2$. But when $m$ is small compared with $n$ you cannot really say anything useful at all.

Comment: @DerekHolt Is there not an exception to that for $n=6$ and $m=5$ with the extra copies of $S_5$ in $S_6$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes you are right! But I believe that is the only exception.

Comment: You have profusion of such subgroups. Say for $m\ge 5$, every subgroup $H$ of $S_m$ of index $>2$ yields a faithful transitive action of $S_m$ on $S_m/H$, and hence an embedding into $S_n$ for $n=|S_m|/|H|$.

Comment: @Cyclicduck: If $G \leq S_n$ and $[S_n:G] = n$, then $G \cong S_{n-1}$.